# Simple SQL request is failing

Tags: mysql, drupal, count

I try to count the number of roles in my Drupal database and with the result execute another statement. But for some reason, it's failing. What do I do wrong?

```
$numberofroles = db_query('SELECT COUNT(rid) FROM {role}');
$roles = 1;

while ($roles < $numberofroles) {
        db_query('INSERT INTO {taxonomy_access_default} (vid, rid, grant_view, grant_update, grant_delete, grant_create, grant_list) VALUES(0, '.$roles.', 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)');
        $roles++;
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about drupal and php but is that curly bracket surrounding the table name `{role}` normal? I would think that it's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget a? ->fetchField() ?

Drupal6:

`$val = db_result(db_query({...}))`

Drupal7:

`$val = db_query({...})->fetchField();`

Comment: I did forget the fetchField()! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What does db_query return? Your SQL query will return a single column and a single row, but does db_query return an integer or the result set as an array?

print $numberofroles (tip: $numberOfRoles is a lot easier to read) and see what the value is. If it prints as `array()` then you need to process the array and extract the value you want, likely `$numberofroles[0][0]`